# How to start Symbian development with Qt?

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia

I am an experienced Qt developer,

I just got Nokia 5233 mobile, I want to develop some Just For Fun applications on top of it.

Can you please tell me what are the prerequisite softwares/libraries I need install on my phone and computer ( Windows 7 32 bit )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the **Nokia Qt SDK 1.0.2** and you will get Qt 4.6.3 and Qt Mobility 1.0.2 together with all the tools you need for building Qt apps for Symbian. Also included Qt 4.7.0 as supported by Nokia's N900 device.

If you need a newer version of Qt (4.7.2, including QML) or Qt Mobility (1.1.1) then install the **Qt SDK 1.1** (currently in beta).

Once the SDK installed, you will find the needed installation packages (*.sis files) for your Symbian^1 device, so that you can install the Qt framework components on your device. Also install the TRK component, for on device debugging.

If you need more help, see the answered questions at http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?219-Qt

Answer (score 1):

See the Recommended SDK(s) on http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/5233/

*Also see*
http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/